# How do I take a screenshot on a Raspberry Pi running Debian Squeeze and LXDE?

Tags: debian, screenshot, lxde, raspberry-pi

How do I take a screenshot on a Raspberry Pi running Debian Squeeze and LXDE?

Shutter is not installed, print screen doesn't appear to work, screen grab is not installed etc.

Comment: Given the nature of the device you'll need to install some software to do this - no idea what. A search for "screen capture debian" or something similar would help.

Comment: Raspberry Pi, I'm so jealous!

Answer (score 1):

```
apt-get install scrot
```

Then read the manual for command line options. If you don't want to open a terminal to take a screenshot every time you can create a launcher for it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `import` from ImageMagick:

```
apt-get install imagemagick
```

#### Selection

When invoking import, the only required argument is a filename, e.g.

```
import screenshot.png
```

When providing only the output filename, you have to drag around the area you want to capture.

#### Full screen

If you want to capture the full screen, you have to invoke import is this fashion:

```
import -window root screenshot.png
```

#### More advanced

Being only arguments, it's pretty easy to fit it to your uses:

```
sleep 2; import -window root ~/Dropbox/screenshot_`date +%F_%H-%M-%S`.png
```

The above sleeps for 2 seconds, then takes a screenshot and puts it in ~/Dropbox. The screenshot name is appended with the current date and time, e.g. `screenshot_2013-02-25_06-42-56.png`

If you want even more, have a look at [Snapper](https://github.com/swordfischer/Snapper) which does all of this, can create screencasts and has support for copying the results to a remote server, amongst other things.